# How to modify DBpedia content

Tags: dbpedia

For example, I want to modify the content of this DBpedia page: http://dbpedia.org/page/A_Game_of_Thrones. In particular, the field

> dbpedia-owl:thumbnail

which incorrectly points to

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/AGameOfThrones.jpg/200px-AGameOfThrones.jpg
```

I want to correct this field by pointing it to `http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/AGameOfThrones.jpg`

Comment: DBpedia data is generated from Wikipedia data.  I don't know whether any post-processing, e.g., to correct errors in the data, is performed, though I doubt it (since the next generation of data would overwrite it with errors, again).  If you've found something wrong, you might go to the Wikipedia page and check whether the data is right there, and if not, fix it.  You might be able to get more up-to-date data with [DBpedia Live](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaLive?v=1cok), although in this case, the values are the same.

Comment: What I meant is that the data in DBpedia is obsolete. The thumbnail fied in DBpedia still points to the old link while the Wikipedia version has changed to a new link.

Comment: Right;  the reason that I pointed out DBpedia Live is because, I think, it's generated from Wikipedia more frequently.  The connection between Wikipedia and DBpedia isn't instantaneous;  the thumbnail value you're seeing should _eventually_ get updated.